# Create Codename One Form in Maven

Tags: codenameone

I migrated my project to Maven and noticed that `right click -> New -> Codename One Resource file/Container/Dialog/Form` is not there anymore.
This is what I have now:
[image]

Where did it move?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a maven goal for this but it isn't exposed in the GUI.
https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/#create-gui-form

Basic usage:

```
mvn cn1:create-gui-form -DclassName=com.example.MyForm
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you planning to add some shortcuts to the File menu in the IDE? (It's just more convenient)

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer is correct, but note that `com.example.MyForm` part **must** be in quotes `""`,

```
mvn cn1:create-gui-form -DclassName="com.example.MyForm"
```

Otherwise there will be an error.